# Armory Wallet With 2BTC Gone After 3 Years! HELP!

Tags: armory, lost-bitcoins, lost-wallet

I purchased 2 bitcoins with CoinBase online 3 years ago. I then sent them to an Armory wallet that I had on a server. Everything transferred successfully and I never thought twice about them disappearing. I have a paper back and an encrypted Armory backup of my wallet. I never made any further transactions.

I finally want to access my BTC in my Armory wallet. I started Armory and the program seemed to freeze many times without loading the block chain. I removed Armory and BitCoin-QT (now BitCoin Core). I installed the newest versions of both programs, downloaded the full block chain and restored my wallet using both the paper backup and the encrypted backup.

The balance of the wallet seems to be 0BTC no matter what backup I use. What happened to my 2BTC and how do I go about getting them back. I have full backup images of the server (c drive and d drive) before removing and reinstalling the software, if that helps.

I just can't seem to figure out where the heck my 2BTC went! Please help!

Here are all the details I could find.

My wallet after using my paper restore has the following two addresses.

```
Transaction #1 (small amount for testing)
Send to address:1CqmjgYj46vRqBxFvbt5WsqMudRShhGKmD
Transaction #: a821fac9e6216975fa8216045a3cd9ae500a82aa251988ca1f301c7287b74ab4

Transaction #2 (sent minutes after transaction 1)
Send to address: 16D1XkRHunUgSfuPDQZSPG42cAicTbSmzu
Transaction #: 5187441186fa834d8a27fb9302bbcb6d3993ff836e1918f8174d5b3266ffb21d

Transaction #3 (sent a month later)
Send to address: 1qjThyMzMrpy3m1esvXF32o3MHVixnxnA
Transaction #: 707e5f96d88134da5f5936b541df19faa9d7e5819d478bd5d533cbb2e9be62c9
```

Answer (score 3):

Try searching the address at blockchain.info with the following link

```
https://blockchain.info/address/<your_addres_here>
```

It will give the current balance of that address, the transactions it was involved. Just in case if your bitcoins were transferred somewhere you would know.

Answer (score 1):

Do not panic, your bitcoins are still in the addresses you provided. By going to https://blockchain.info/address/ you can see that they contain the following amounts:

**Testing:**

*public address #1: 1NNcPWKhowH7QhKDAjRYrdBFVbAHoDDcCe    0BTC*

public address #2: 1CqmjgYj46vRqBxFvbt5WsqMudRShhGKmD    ~0.01BTC

**The ones you care about:**

*public address #3: 16D1XkRHunUgSfuPDQZSPG42cAicTbSmzu    ~0.98BTC*

public address #4: 1qjThyMzMrpy3m1esvXF32o3MHVixnxnA    1BTC

You probably loaded the wrong private key into the Armoury client, look for the wallet.dat files in directory Armoury and try again.